# Windows services's Scheduled execution delayed after restart

Tags: c#, windows-services

I created a windows service which is scheduled to run every day at a specific time. I have used **Timers** in it. It runs successfully.

For testing the service I reduced the interval to 5 mins and it runs every 5 mins but one problem is that when **I restart the system between the Timer interval It executes after an extra 23 seconds** which I think is the time the system takes to restart. Check the log file for example.

but **it should execute after exactly 5 mins independent of the system restart.** How can I do that?

I tried looking up but majority solutions relate to automatic delayed start type.

Thanks in advance.

These are the log file entries:
    Another entry at 24-Jul-15 11:02:00 AM
    Another entry at 24-Jul-15 11:07:00 AM
    Another entry at 24-Jul-15 11:12:00 AM
    Another entry at 24-Jul-15 11:17:00 AM //System Restart
    Another entry at 24-Jul-15 11:22:23 AM //System Restart
    Another entry at 24-Jul-15 11:27:47 AM
    Another entry at 24-Jul-15 11:32:47 AM
    Another entry at 24-Jul-15 11:37:47 AM

Here is the code:

```
public partial class ScheduledService : ServiceBase
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    DateTime today;// = new DateTime();
    DateTime yesterday;
    public ScheduledService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        today = new DateTime();
        today = DateTime.Today;

        TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(11, 02, 0);
        today = today.Date + ts;

        yesterday = new DateTime();
        yesterday = today.AddDays(-1);
    } 

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        //add this line to text file during start of service  
        TraceService1("start service at:" + DateTime.Now);

        //handle Elapsed event
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);

        //This statement is used to set interval to 1 minute (= 60,000 milliseconds)     

        timer.Interval = today.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds * 1000;

        //enabling the timer
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }   

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        timer.Enabled = false;
        TraceService1("stopping service at:" + DateTime.Now); //

    }
    private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        TraceService("Another entry at " + DateTime.Now); 

        if (timer.Interval != 5 * 60 * 1000)//86400000
        {
            timer.Interval = 5 * 60 * 1000;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the entire purpose of this service just to wait until the appropriate time and then to do something? If so, why aren't you just using the Windows Scheduler?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Because I was asked to create a windows service :p